# uploaded image does not display correcty in Firefox, iphone Safari, google chrome but works in internet explore

Tags: django, google-app-engine, jinja2, blobstore

I am following [this Google tutorial](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/blobstore/overview) to upload and display an image. 
My test site is http://dnk-test1.appspot.com/testfile
Everything works except that when I click on the image name, the Firefox, iphone safari, google chrome browser just write out strange character like

```
����JFIF��XExifMM*�i&�� ����C     ��C��� "�� ���}!1AQa"q2���#B��R��$3br� %&'()*456789:CDEFGHIJSTUVWXYZcdefghijstuvwxyz��������������������������������������������������������������������������� ���w!1AQaq"2�B���� #3R�br� $4�%�
```

When I click View -> Character Encoding and choose any Encoding, the image is display correctly.

However, on IE, the image is display correctly.

I am using 
Firefox 18.0.1
IE 10

UPDATE 1: On localhost, image displays correctly for all kind of browsers.

UPDATE 2: Added screen shot of Blob Viewer
[image]

UPDATE 3: Add code

views.py

```
class UploadHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreUploadHandler):
    def post(self):
        # アップロードされたファイルの情報を取得
        files = self.get_uploads('file')
        blob_info = files[0]

        # redirect メソッドが上手く動かないので、ステータスコードとヘッダを使って
        # ブラウザにリダイレクトを指示
        headers = dict(Location=utils.url_for('myapp/serve', blob_key=blob_info.key()))
        return werkzeug.Response(None, headers=headers, status=302)


class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        return self.send_blob(blob_info)

def testfile(request):
    # アップロード用の URL を作成
    # アップロードに成功したら core/upload エンドポイントへ移動させる
    upload_url = blobstore.create_upload_url(utils.url_for('myapp/upload'))

    # Blobstore に保存されているファイルをすべて取得
    files = blobstore.BlobInfo.all()

    # テンプレートを使って表示
    data = dict(
            upload_url=upload_url,
            files=files)
    return utils.render_to_response('myapp/testfile.html', data)
```

urls.py

```
Rule('/testfile', endpoint='testtile', view='myapp.views.testfile'),
    Rule('/upload', endpoint='upload', view=('myapp.views.UploadHandler', (), {})),
    Rule('/serve/<blob_key>', endpoint='serve', view=('myapp.views.ServeHandler', (), {})),
```

testfile.html

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Top Page - core</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <form action="{{ upload_url }}" method="POST" enctype="multipart/form-data">
            Upload File:<input type="file" name="file"><br>
            <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
        </form>

        <h2>Uploaded Files</h2>
        <ul>
            {% for file in files %}
            <li><a href="{{ url_for('myapp/serve', blob_key=file.key()     ) }}">{{ file.filename }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
    </body>
</html>
```

UPDATE 4: I found [this page](http://tnakamura.hatenablog.com/entry/20101209/kay_blobstore), where the image is uploaded and its thumbnail image is display correctly, the normal image is not display correctly. The difference is that when the thumbnail image is displayed, `mimetype='image/jpg'` is used. Therefore, I think I need to add this code to somewhere, but I dont know where.

Comment: Sounds like the content-type header is missing or incorrect. IE usually tries to parse it, which is sometimes convenient but has its own issues, while other browsers tend to be stricter about it.

Comment: thanks for help. I just added UPDATE1. Btw, the <head></head> contains <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">

Comment: The image doesn't have a <meta> because it's not html, but the http header (use livehttpheader or chrome developer console) says it's text/html. I suspect something goes wrong on upload, as the content type is stored along with the blob.

Comment: I added Update 2. I think the upload is correct since when I check the Content Type on Blob View, file types are correct. It also strange that it works on localhost but not appspot.com.

Comment: Is the werkzeug machinery setting content type automatically somehow? Try adding a new entry to app.yaml pointing to a regular webapp2 handler and serve directly from root like /serve instead of /testapp/serve

Answer (score 1):

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        return self.send_blob(blob_info)
```

should be change to

```
class ServeHandler(blobstore_handlers.BlobstoreDownloadHandler):
    def get(self, blob_key):
        blob_key = str(urllib.unquote(blob_key))
        blob_info = blobstore.BlobInfo.get(blob_key)
        return self.send_blob(blob_info,'image/jpg')
```